# How to add a border to only percentage of width of element, CSS Trick

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

### The Issue...

Once again I am searching for a cool CSS trick to help me to achieve an effect whilst preventing the use of untidy HTML...

The following image shows what I am trying to achieve, ***notice the top and bottom borders only stretching around 70% of the width...***

[image: Percentage Width Borders]

### A Starting Point

As a starting point I have created the above using what I would call 'untidy HTML' to add these dividers to the list.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E93UE/

***You will see I have `<li class="divider><!-- Divider --></li>`, this is what I want to get rid of if possible***

### My Question

So, if the above has not explained well enough, I would like to apply a border to a block element, but only show the border for a specific width of the whole element.

Obviously this cannot be achieved using just `border:XXX`, it is likely to need some `:before` and `:after` selectors...

### Possible Solutions...

I have had two thoughts of how this could be achieved, one is not too practical, and the other I am not too sure how to implement (these are just ideas):

1. Set the width of the list element and give it `overflow:visible`, all elements within have `position:absolute` and then just apply margins to bring the elements out of the list box... (***not a good fix, prefer my original***)
2. The other solution, which I am not too sure how to implement, may be the way to go. By apply two `:before` elements with `position:absolute` you could overlay the edges of each border (***I think***)

Comment: test it with a css3 transparent gradient :)

Comment: @MichaelUnterthurner I don't particularly want to use CSS3 for this as it needs to be browser compatible. In addition, I cannot see how transparent gradient could help here...

Comment: What does "browser compatible" mean? As in, which browsers/versions?

Comment: @thirtydot Apologies, I mean the solution needs to work in older browsers such as, dare I say it, IE8+

Comment: You can specify the start of the gradient with percent and the end... but that wasn't the question..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recreated your divider using `:before`/`:after` pseudo-elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/E93UE/1/

```css
#staff_list li:first-child:before, #staff_list li:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -26px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #b9b7b6;
}
#staff_list li:first-child:before {
    top: -14px;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

The numbers need tweaking, and you need to test it when you have more text, but it's probably close enough. I made other changes to help this solution work, compare your original demo to mine.

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you +1. My only comment would be that `:first:child` is CSS3 and is not supported in IE8 (I think)?

Comment: This should work in IE8. `:first-child` is CSS2 and works in IE8, `:last-child` is CSS3 and does not work in IE8.

Comment: Ah, I see. Brilliant, just need to jiggle the margins and I think this is it. Thank you very much, I will come back if I have any problems :-)

Answer (score 19):

Give a border to `:after` pseudo-element ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MdT9G/)):

```
.separated:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 1em auto 0;
    border-bottom: solid;
}
```

Comment: Good solution, this is the sort of thing I imagined. Just trying to implement it, it isn't quite working yet...

Comment: The problem I am having is that the `:after` element is not applying the margin relative to the floated element...

Comment: Nice solution! And I thinned it up with `border-bottom: 1px solid black;`.